# EC2: permissions are denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, pip

Am a developer i have no good knowledge on how to setup a server on `AWS EC2` instance but what am trying to do is to setup `thumbor` server on `EC2` `thumbor` is built with `python` and, am follwing this steps to get it up and running [setup thumbor](http://www.dadoune.com/blog/best-thumbnailing-solution-set-up-thumbor-on-aws/).
However, when i try to do install the following package using the user of the the `EC2` `ec2-user`:

```
pip install numpy
```

i got this error:

```
  running install_lib
    creating /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy': Permission denied

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Ibmsr4/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-afbRUs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Ibmsr4/numpy
```

i switched to the roor user and triedn to install the same package i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
```

My question is what cause this problem and how i could install this package so i can continue the proccess of seting up the server !
Note: am using putty on Windows also i successed to install many packages previously so i can tell my creation to the EC2 is correct.

Comment: Probably solved by updating `setuptools` and `pip` to the latest versions.

Comment: `numpy` can be difficult to install. I recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda), which also installs `pandas` and myriad other useful data libraries.

Comment: I tried all solution didn't work , but this manual installtion worked for me
[link](http://techtorials.me/linux/install-python-in-home-linux-directory/)